# Does RHEL5 have a 'Quit trying to help me' setting?

Tags: settings, redhat, rhel5

I set it up the way I want it.  It keeps changing it (for example, setting up the NIC's and bonding settings in the shop for the install particulars, then RH keeps changing it.  One of many many examples)

So, a setting that says 'I'll set it up the way I want, and if there's problems I'll deal with them.  Quit trying to help me".

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps ask over at http://serverfault.com

Comment: Well, I tried.  Can't get past the stupid captcha.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that there is a "Help Me" setting. What you are describing sounds like configurations being overwritten by defaults or processes. For instance, network files will be overwritten if you have DHCP enabled. You can customize your /etc/resolv.conf file all you want, but if you have dhcp enabled, that file will be updated and your changes lost. (unless you make it read only)

Is this what you are talking about?